# Does the prohibition of bestiality apply to fish

Tags: halacha, sexuality, noachide-laws, arayot, fish

Does the Halacha’s prohibition of bestiality apply to fish? The reason I ask is because Halacha distinguishes between fish and non fish animals for other aspects of Halacha, such as the need for shechita.

Or is the Halacha the same for fish as it is for other animals?

Comment: I can't see why it would be different.

Comment: The rambam just says בהמה חיה או עוף

Comment: The question is discussed here: https://beinenu.com/system/files/alonim/858_69_82.pdf That PDF is unavailable for download and is not archived by the Internet Archive.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/98972/11532

Comment: @TheGRAPKE try this https://beinenu.com/system/files/alonim/858_69_82.pdf?download=1

Comment: @RabbiKaii בטעמא דקרא כתב דארור שוכב עם "כל" בהמה בא לרבות עם דולפנין, והקשיתי קמיה
מרן שליט"א שהרי דולפנין הוא דג ובמנ"ח מצוה ר"י כתב שאין חיוב רביעה בדג
דלשום דבר אין חית הים שוה לחיה חוץ מכלאים שהגמ' בב"ק דנה, [ועי' תוס' ב"ק שם
וכבר דנו בזה לענין שביתת בהמתו אם מצווה על דגים ועי' באהע"ז סי' ה' בפ"ת שהביא
דיש איסור סירוס על דגים] וכתב לי מרן שליט"א דדברי המנ"ח הם חידוש, עכ"ד, עוד
שאלתי קמיה מרן שליט"א דאם הדיוק נכון מדוע העיר כן רק בפרשת כי תבוא דהוא בענין
ארור הרי גם בפרשת אחרי מות כתוב ו"בכל" בהמה לא תתן שכבתך ונרבה גם דולפנין
שחייב מיתה, והשיבני מרן דהיינו הך וחייב גם מיתה.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE https://www.sefaria.org/Minchat_Chinukh.210.1.1

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/119840/759

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gemara [(Sanhedrin 58a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.58a.8?lang=bi) teaches that the prohibition for Noahides to have relations with land-based *non-humans* is derived from the commandment: “and they shall become one flesh” i.e. they may only engage in relations that can result in bearing offspring, which would seem from this Gemara to exclude fish as well.

However, with regards to punishing a Jew, it seems from the [Minchas Chinuch (Mitzvah 210)](https://www.sefaria.org/Minchat_Chinukh.210.1?lang=bi) that he exempts sea creatures from the prohibitions related to non-human land animals, being that from the Gemara ([Bava Kama 55a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.55a.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) it seems that the only prohibition that includes fish is the prohibition of **Kilayim**, meaning *mixing different species*.

Comment: @IsaacMoses If I understand what User123 is trying to say, it's that the prohibition for a Noahide and the prohibition for a Jew are different. I tried to cleanup the confusion by adjusting his language slightly and providing links to the texts. Frankly, I don't understand how this answer, as presented, got so many upvotes and awarded as correct answer.